# Access GCP and PG Admin

Tags: postgresql, authentication, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin

I am working on postgres db which is on GCP server.
Usually for log in I need to go to gcp then connections and add my public ip address into Authorized networks (see image), in that way I can log in into PGAdmin, put the host,db name, port and password.
But looks like my public ip address change frequently and this is normal but there is another way to login my Postgresdb on GCP with PGADMIN without adding my public ip address?

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Setup the Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy on your local machine. Then you do not need to authorize IP addresses.

[About the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)